# I have written code for simple AngularJS JavaScript but not working properly only root scope is updating but not the other two why

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have written code for simple AngularJS JavaScript but not working properly.

Only root scope is updating but not the other two why I want to update `FirstCtrl` and `SecondCtrl` to be updated when I update Root Scope, But this is not working the way I expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
        <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{ data.message}}</h1>
        </div>
            <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{ data.message}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js contains:

```
function FirstCtrl($scope){
}
function SecondCtrl($scope){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
});
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="message1">
      <h1>{{ message1}}</h1>
  </div>
      <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="message2">
      <h1>{{ message2}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Define controller in module. It will create different scope for different controller.

Answer (score 2):

scope properties must be be in controller you must have an app in first and declare controller in your app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
        <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{ data.message}}</h1>
        </div>
            <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{ data.message}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js :

```
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("FirstCtrl",function($scope){
   });
 app.controller("SecondCtrl",function($scope){
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do like this:

```
angular.module('myApp'[])
  .controller('FirstCtrl',FirstCtrl)
  .controller('SecondCtrl',SecondCtrl);

function FirstCtrl($scope){
}
function SecondCtrl($scope){
}
```

In index.html
Give reference main.js and give name of application

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```